# Add Filter to get_next_posts_link

Tags: plugins, posts, filters, links

As we see in [the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L2179), we can apply filters for `$attr`.

So I create something like this

```
function asdff(){
    return 'class="iamclass"';
}
add_filter('get_next_posts_link', 'asdff',10,2);
```

or

```
function asdff($attr){
    $attr .= "class='iamclass'";
    return $attr;
}
add_filter('get_next_posts_link', 'asdff',10,2);
```

It should be like this at front end `<a href="#nextpage" class='iamclass'>`, but it doesnt work. My class doesnt appear. How to achive that, did i miss something at `add_filter` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed add a filter to `get_next_posts_link`, but it has a different name, namely [`next_posts_link_attributes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/next_posts_link_attributes/) Complete code would look like this:

```
add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', 'wpse_230552');
function wpse_230552() {
    return 'class="iamclass"';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the filter's name is `next_posts_link_attributes` but not `get_next_posts_link` as that the name of the function.

So try instead:

```
add_filter( 'next_posts_link_attributes', 'wpse_next_posts_link_attributes' );
```

where `wpse_next_posts_link_attributes()` is your filter callback.

Example (untested):

```
function wpse_next_posts_link_attributes( $attributes )
{
    return 'class="iamclass"';
}
```

Note that this will override earlier filter callbacks and it looks like the attributes are not escaped, so watch out for that too.